# Validar valor de um select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

```
<label>Itinerário</label>
<select id="itinerario" name="itinerario" class="form-control form-control-sm" required readonly>
    <option value="" selected>Selecione um itinerário</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
if($('#itinerario :selected').text() == ""){
    alert('Elemento vazio!');
}
```

Estou tentado fazer o código acima porém ele não reconhece o value, preciso que quando fique selecionado nesse value="" vazio, apareça o alert.

Comment: E quando esse `if` é executado?

Comment: Quando carrega a página ele já válida.

Comment: Você está usando jQuery? Se sim, seria legal você [edit] a pergunta e adicionar a tag [tag:jquery].

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o a função [val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) e o evento [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) do jquery:

Veja o código abaixo:

```js
function validarSelect(){
  if(!$('#itinerario').val()){
    alert('Elemento vazio!');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#itinerario').on('change', function(){
    validarSelect();
  });
 validarSelect();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<label>Itinerário</label>
<select id="itinerario" name="itinerario" class="form-control form-control-sm" required readonly>
    <option value="" selected>Selecione um itinerário</option>
    <option value="2" >Opção 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Você poderia usar `$('#itinerario').on('change', validarSelect);` visto que a função não usa nenhum de seus argumentos...

Comment: Correto, obrigado.